# MockMVC returns 406 for the list of objects (for one object test works), why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In spring boot application (springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'), I have two ReST endpoints. One returns object, and second returns list of object. I try to write test for this endpoints with [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html).

Test for single object, works as expected. Tests for list of objects returns `406` instead of `200`. Below is my code, controller + tests for it.
Single object ReST:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"/example", "/example.html"})
public ResponseEntity<SampleObject> example() {
    SampleObject sampleObj = generateSampleObject();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(sampleObj, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
public void shouldCheckExamplePage() throws Exception {
    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/example")
    .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
}
```

ReST endpoint for the list:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index.html"})
public ResponseEntity<List<SampleObject>> all() {
    List<SampleObject> sampleObjectList = generateListOfSampleObject();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(sampleObjectList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
public void shouldCheckHomePage() throws Exception {
    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")
            .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
}
```

What is a difference? Why for one object test works, but not for list?

**Added:**
when I start app, in browser all works fine, both endpoints.

Comment: As a note, `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8` exists for a reason. Please turn up logging for `org.springframework.web` to DEBUG and post the results; additionally, you should be getting a report from MockMvc on your test console.

Comment: Run your test with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` on head of your test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets examine the code:

- `HTTP 406` shows that your backend didn't return the response client requests for.
- Your client(your tests) requests for `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`
- `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` means content type is `JSON` and it is encoded in the `UTF-8` character encoding

A possible reason may be in your list response you have some objects that are not encoded in UTF-8